# Get the counts of unique values on conditions

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I would like to get the number of time a team Win in a seasons.

I have a dataframe looking like this:

```
Date          Team    Win   Player    SHOT
2014-20-10     CHI     1    Benoit     1
2014-20-10     CHI     1    Benoit     0
2014-20-10     CHI     1    Benoit     0
2014-20-10     CHI     1    Mickael    1
2014-23-10     CHI     0    Phillips   1
```

So the problem is the following, If I sum the Win I get too many win since the values is duplicate for every shot of every player .

I have done a unique value column merge Date, Win and Team and I am able to get a count of those unique value.

```
df.new["Unique"] = df.new["Date"].map(str) + df.new["Team"] + df.new["Win"]
counts = df.new['Unique'].value_counts()
df.new.groupby(['Unique'])['Win'].sum()
```

I have try two technique to get a sum of the win but every time I just get the number of time the unique value is in the data. What I want is the total of win for each team over the season. So the every time a unique value is associated with a 1 in the Win column I want +1 and when it is 0 +0...SO I get the total win for each team over the season.

I hope I am clear. I would have done this with aggregate in R but I am new to python. How would you do it ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have perfect data:

```
df.groupby(['Date','Team'])['Win'].max()
```

Since there should only be one result for a team on a date.
and for the all dates:

```
df.groupby(['Date','Team'])['Win'].max().groupby(level=1).sum()
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe `pivot_table` would also work here.

```
wins = pd.pivot_table(df, 'Win', 'Date', 'Team').sum()
```